# RSyntaxTextArea numbers followed by letters are highlighted in a different way [Java]

Tags: java, jtextarea, rsyntaxtextarea

I know my qustion is not that clear but I'll try to explain it here:
In my java application I am using the RSyntaxTextArea library. When I try to write a string composed by some digits followed by letters (i.e. 2c, 7x, 12g) this string changes color, different from the usual numbers or ordinary strings.
My question is: How can I make this type of 'numbers' to remain with black as foreground color?

[image]

Thanks for your tips!

Comment: Snapshot uploaded!

Comment: which kind of token this should be?

Comment: did you specify the language that you want to highlight.and what is 234 it's not valid code.

Comment: This is a custom language, I have never added a Token for that kind of string. "234" is just a random number to let you see the normal color of numbers..

Comment: i tested but all black text if i don't set a style.dis you set a style like `textArea.setSyntaxEditingStyle()` .see this http://i.imgur.com/CuPzfNM.png

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was going wrong. I used TokenMakerMaker to create my own language, and in the flex file it creates, an `ErrorNumberFormat` line :

```
{ErrorNumberFormat}         { addToken(Token.ERROR_NUMBER_FORMAT); }
```

So, probably, while using this as custom language in RSTA, whenever the user type something like "3tr" (string composed my digit(s) followed by letter(s)), the scheme recognized it like an error within the format of the number and colores it in a different way. 
To fix my problem I simply write this code in my application:

```
SyntaxScheme scheme = textArea.getSyntaxScheme();
scheme.getStyle(Token.ERROR_NUMBER_FORMAT).foreground = Color.BLACK;
textArea.repaint();
textArea.revalidate();
```

to set the color of this Token to Black!